# Selenium Java String assertion failing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I used the Selenium IDE to record a test case. The goal was to assert the correctness of the static text on a page. I exported the test case as Java / JUnit 4 / WebDriver and the code looked like this.

```
assertEquals("Please select the ratings year and file type for the data that you are attempting to upload. \n\n Ratings Year: The year in which the data was submitted/collected.", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p")).getText());
```

I edited the format of the code a bit to match how the rest of the case is coded:

```
    // Expected text for each part of the reporting year page
    String rMainHeading = "Upload Data Files";
    String rHeading = "Select Ratings Year and File Type for Clinical Measures Data";
    String rBody1 = "Please select the ratings year and file type for the data that you are attempting to upload. \n\n Ratings Year: The year in which the data was submitted/collected.";

    // Reporting year page text locations
    WebElement reportingMainH = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));
    WebElement reportingHeader = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2"));
    WebElement reportingBody1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p"));

    System.out.println("stopA");
    // Checking the Reporting Year page text is displayed as expected
    try {
        assertEquals ((reportingMainH.getText()),rMainHeading);
        assertEquals ((reportingHeader.getText()),rHeading);
        System.out.println("stop1");
        assertEquals ((reportingBody1.getText()),rBody1);
        System.out.println("stop2");

        WebElement reportingWords = driver.findElement(By.id("submissionForm"));
        String reportingYearText = reportingWords.getText();
        System.out.println("4) The static text on the Reporting Year page has been confirmed.");
        //System.out.println(reportingYearText);
        setupScript.screenshot(driver);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("*******The text on the page does not match the expect results of XXX-1938. This case has failed.");
    }
```

The test case is failing after "stop1" so the I'm not sure how to make this string assertion work. I tried using a String.join, but that also failed.
[Here is what the element looks likes upon inspection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJx91.jpg)

How can I deal with the \n to assert this text correctly?

Comment: print out `reportingBody1.getText()` and copy and paste it to the variable `rbody1`

Comment: @LINGS it prints out with a blank line in between the two statements, so I'm still not sure how to code that since using \n doesn't seem to be working (or I'm using it incorrectly).

Comment: I figured this out. Removing the spaces before and after \n\n fixed it! So it looked like this: String rBody1 = "Please select the ratings year and file type for the data that you are attempting to upload.\n\nRatings Year: The year in which the data was submitted/collected.";

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do here is just print

> reportingBody1.getText()

and copy the text which is displaying in console to [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad). In WordPad we can easily see number of line breaks and space exactly. So that we can easily figure it out how to write means with spaces, `/n`, etc. in expected value in assertions.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is leading and trailing spaces, simply trimming the String from `reportingBody1.getText()` would work.

`assertEquals(reportingBody1.getText().trim(), rBody1);`

Comment: unfortunately they reverted the code back to a previous version and I won't be able to test this for another week or so. I will give this a try when they redeploy and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! :) Let me know if it works when you test this.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for testing it and letting me know!